# quickbook desktop Webconnector : Insufficient permission level to perform this action

Tags: qbxml

I'm trying to open a file from a old Company in `quickBooks desktop webconnector`.
This time it Returns `status code = 3260` and also show message like

> Insufficient permission level to perform this action

Comment: it sounds like you don't have the right access level.

Comment: improved formatting. please use all formatting Options available to make you question better understandable and make it easier to read. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Currently The user level permission is MultiuserMode. We want change as a "Admin" single user mode

2)When we open quickbooks desktop webconnector company file.We use below credential.

3)default admin credential in quickbooks desktop webConnector

userName : Admin 
password : (no password)